# python click help formatting newline

Tags: python, python-click

I am seeing that a newline is not being preserved in my EPILOG? I want to know why if I see that newline remains only when a line has `74` characters?

```
# http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/

import click, sys

def main_caller(*args, **kwargs):
    print('act on arguments', args, kwargs)

EPILOG = '''
# oneline
# twoline

\n
# oneline with 74char                                                   x
# twoline with 74char                                                   x
'''

@click.group(help='wwwwwwwwww', epilog=EPILOG, invoke_without_command=True, chain=True)
@click.argument('start_or_stop')
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', default=False, help='Print Verbose messages')
@click.option('-l', '--logfile', help='Path to logfile to store log messages')
@click.option('-a', '--action', multiple=True, type=click.Choice(['act1', 'act2', 'act3']), default=['act1', 'act2'])
def cli(*args, **kwargs):
    '''foo bar'''
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False)
def cmd1(*args, **kwargs):
    print('cmd1', args, kwargs)
    return 'cmd11111'

@cli.command()
@click.option('-x', '--xxx', default='x')
def cmd2(*args, **kwargs):
    print('cmd2', args, kwargs)
    return 'cmd22222'

@cli.resultcallback()
def process_pipeline(*args, **kwargs):
    print('process', args, kwargs)
    print('args', sys.argv[1:])     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Output is:

```
/click_sandbox.py --help
2017/02/24 19:31:43 Platform overridden to 'RHEL5_64'
Usage: click_sandbox.py [OPTIONS] START_OR_STOP COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2
                        [ARGS]...]...

  wwwwwwwwww

Options:
  -v, --verbose TEXT             Print Verbose messages
  -l, --logfile TEXT             Path to logfile to store log messages
  -a, --action [act1|act2|act3]
  --help                         Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  cmd1
  cmd2

  # oneline # twoline

  # oneline with 74char                                                   x
  # twoline with 74char                                                   x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your newlines are not being preserved because the epilog writer does word wrapping.  This can be solved with a subclass to `click.Group`, by creating a `format_epilog()` which does not do word wrapping:

```
class SpecialEpilog(click.Group):
    def format_epilog(self, ctx, formatter):
        if self.epilog:
            formatter.write_paragraph()
            for line in self.epilog.split('\n'):
                formatter.write_text(line)

# Tell click to use our epilog formatter
@click.group(cls=SpecialEpilog,
    help='wwwwwwwwww', epilog=EPILOG, invoke_without_command=True, chain=True)
....
```

Comment: This works so long as EPILOG has printable characters, if I put just a couple of newlines ('\n\n\n') it does nothing unless I anchor them with a printable character. Any ideas how to modify the above to tack a couple of newlines in a similar manner?

Comment: @slm, Great question.  Not a use case I had considered. Looking through the framework, the answer appears to be yes, but it will involve more overrides.  If you pop up a question , I will gladly type up an answer.

Comment: @StephenRauch - sure thing, been wrestling w/ this the last few days and didn't see a a way to accomplish it easily (I'm new to Python).

Comment: @StephenRauch - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124680/how-to-add-multiple-blank-lines-to-the-end-of-the-usage-message-produced-by-the

Answer (score 30):

In Click 7.0 you use the \b marker to indicate that the formatting is to be preserved e.g.:

```
This paragraph is formatted normally and Click does
not preserve new lines.

\b
This paragraph is formatted as it
appears in the source:
item 1
item 2

This paragraph is formatted normally and Click does
not preserve new lines.
```

Comment: From the docs, this feature appears to be available in all versions.

Comment: From experiments with Click 7.0, it seems the sequence needed in a help text to trigger this is '\b\n', i.e. backspace followed by newline.

Comment: @AndreasMaier - prepending my help string with `\b\n` prevented re-wrapping. thanks!

Comment: Link to click rewrapping discussed here: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/documentation/#preventing-rewrapping